# "Open With" dialog appears when double clicking on a local drive in My Computer

Tags: windows-xp

I noticed that when i click my local drives`(C:,D:)` i got `open with` Dialog box..... I am using windows xp... Then i found `autorun.txt` file was added to all the drives...

How to solve this?  Any suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem after [Antivirus 2010](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) tried to install itself on one of the work computers I care for (I say try, because the user was a limited user, so Antivirus 2010 couldn't install itself!).

Like **[Bobby](https://superuser.com/questions/117821/open-with-dialog-appears-when-double-clicking-on-a-local-drive-in-my-computer/117823#117823)** mentioned, try using an antivirus or anti-malware program to check for and clean the infection. I recommend [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware program](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php).

What I ended up doing to stop the "Open With" box from showing (whenever the user tried to open an Internet Explorer link) was create a new profile.

From my administrator account, I copied all of the data they needed to keep (found in `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>`) to another drive.

Then, using the User Profiles Tool (Right-click on My Computer, "Properties", Advanced tab, 
"Settings" button in the User Profiles box), I deleted the profile and created a new one, and then copied all of the documents back in.

Answer (score 0):

You've most likely malware/viruses/trojans on your PC, go get an Antivirus Software (like [AntiVir](http://www.free-av.de/)).

Oh, and just delete the files (f.e. via command line)...if they're coming back, see my first sentence.